# Sum involving iid Poisson random variables

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, solution-verification

Suppose $X_i \stackrel{\text{iid}}{\sim} \text{Poisson}(\lambda)$ and consider $Y_n \equiv \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{X_i - \lambda}{i}$

I want to show that $Y_n$ converges almost surely but diverges in absolute value almost surely, i.e. $$(1) \quad Y_\infty \equiv \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{i} (X_i - \lambda) \text{ exists a.s., but } (2) \quad A_\infty \equiv \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{i} |X_i -  \lambda| \text{ diverges a.s.} $$

$(1)$ can be seen as an easy consequence of Kolmogorov's two series theorem.  $Z_i \equiv (X_i -\lambda)/i$ has $E(Z_i) = 0$ and $\text{Var}(Z_i) = \lambda/i^2$ so that both $\sum E(Z_i), \sum \text{Var}(Z_i)$ are convergent series.

I'm not 100% sure how to proceed on $(2)$, but perhaps the following argument works:

If $\lambda \not \in \mathbb{N}$, we immediately have $|X_i - \lambda| \ge \min \{\lceil{\lambda} \rceil - \lambda, \lambda - \lfloor{\lambda} \rfloor\} \equiv c > 0$ for every $i$ almost surely.  Thus $$A_\infty \ge c \sum_{i \ge 1} \frac{1}{i} = \infty$$

Now if $\lambda \in \mathbb{N}$, things become more complicated trying to do this rigorously even when the problem is intuitively the same.  Maybe we need to use Kolmogorov's three series theorem?  We know that if $A_\infty$ exists as a limit almost surely, then for every $t \in (0, \infty)$ we must have $$S(t) \equiv \sum_{i = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{i} E(|X_i - \lambda| \mathbf{1}(|X_i - \lambda| \leq i t)) < \infty $$

Pick $t = 2$ and we obviously have $\mathbf{1}(|X_i - \lambda| \leq 2) \leq \mathbf{1}(|X_i - \lambda| \leq 2i)$ as $2i \ge 2$.  Furthermore, $$\forall i \in \mathbb{N}, \quad E(|X_i - \lambda| \mathbf{1}(|X_i - \lambda| \leq 2))\ge 2P(X_i = \lambda +2) \equiv \delta > 0$$ so finally we obtain $$\infty = \delta \sum_{i \ge 1} \frac{1}{i} \leq \sum_{i \ge 1} E(|X_i - \lambda| \mathbf{1}(|X_i - \lambda| \leq 2) \leq S(2)$$
so we have a contradiction and we can conclude.  Does this work?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick way to do part (2).

Let $\xi_i:= |X_i-\lambda|$. Then $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac1i (\xi_i-\Bbb E[\xi_i])$ converges a.s. by the same reasoning as in part (1). Note that $\sum_1^n \frac1i \Bbb E[\xi_i] \sim \Bbb E[\xi_1]\log n$.

Thus for almost every $\omega$ we see that $\big(\sum_{i=1}^n \frac1i \xi_i(\omega)\big) - \Bbb E[\xi_1]\log n$ is a convergent (hence bounded) sequence, which implies that $\sum_1^n \frac1i \xi_i(\omega)$ diverges on the same set of $\omega$.

Comment: May I request that you use a different notation for $|X_i - \lambda|$ considering that the original question defined $Y_i$ already?  This would reduce my confusion.

Comment: Thanks I didn't see that before. lol